# Returning a Single Value using MySQL and PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, http, phpmyadmin

I am getting users to enter their email and passwords, and with those details I wish to echo their username from the table. This is so I can demonstrate that I have retrieved a value from the table.

I do know that my query works on phpmyadmin and that the email and password is being retrieved in my php as well. The error I am getting with my current code is HTTP Error 500:

```
mysql_connect($database,$username,$password);
@mysql_select_db($username) or die ("Unable to select database");

$email = mysql_escape_string ($_POST['email']);
$password = mysql_escape_string ($_POST['password']);
$email = stripslashes($email);
$password = stripslashes($password);
$email = mysql_escape_string($email);
$password = mysql_escape_string($password);


$SQL = "SELECT Name FROM users WHERE BINARY Email = '$email' and BINARY password = '$password'";

$result = mysql_query($SQL) or die("Unable to Run Query");

$value = mysql_fetch_object($result) or die("Unable to Fetch Object");

echo "<h2>$value</h2>" or die("Unable to Echo");
```

Comment: If you have the appropriate access, you may be able to assist yourself by enabling error reporting for PHP.  display_errors = on shouold be added to your PHP.ini file. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053424/how-do-i-get-php-errors-to-display

Comment: Maybe can help https://www.lifewire.com/500-internal-server-error-explained-2622938

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the statment to

```
$SQL = "SELECT Name FROM users WHERE BINARY Email = '".$email."' and BINARY 
        password = '".$password."'";
```

Comment: That solution gave me the same error as before, any other solutions or ideas?

Comment: what is binary in your statement?

Answer (score 0):

**First of all do not use mysql_*, as they are deprecated**. You can achieve this like:

```
$result = mysql_query($SQL);
if( mysql_num_rows($result) > 0 )
{
    $data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // $data is an array, to return a single value, do it like $data['name']
}
```

Comment: You advise not to use them, and then use them in your answer?

Comment: I am just telling you how can achieve this. You can change it to **mysqli_***

Comment: Its returning a blank page (which is great cause that means there is no error!). How can I see if its returned the right result?

Answer (score 0):

You should really abandon the old mysql connector and switch to MySQLi.

However, you should take a look at [mysql_result()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php)